# How to reset visual editor zoom at VisualStudio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

well, long story short: I had an 4k monitor and my visualstudio worked fine at it, but then I change it back for an 1080p screen, and now my vs2019 is like this:

[image]

Someone knows how to fix that?

Comment: Checking if I understand this correctly: the Visual Studio IDE itself is fine, but the Form that you are designing is now "too big" and you want it scaled down? See if this helps (for .NET 5 and Core 3.1): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/forms/autoscale?view=netdesktop-5.0

Comment: It works! Thanks. I changed all the forms to autoScale = DPI :)